# Drag and Drop Outlook attachments to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I am unable to drag and drop attachments from Outlook for Mac directly into Chrome.

I am able to do this in Safari, but not in Chrome. I have seen that some people have fixed this issue on Windows computers by making sure Chrome is not running as Admin, but I am having this issue on Mac. To clarify, I am using Outlook for Mac. There doesn't seem to be a way to run Chrome as Admin be default. So, I am confused as to what the issue may be.